# Ccreating an entity relationship diagram in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

**I want to create a database for my football (soccer) manager/training program:**
I want it to store players and managers in the database, they will all have their own username and passwords etc. they should also have a position in which will be listed as an attribute along with their name, password etc.

Each position has different attributes (If possible I would want these to be stored in a separate table i.e. a goalkeeper table, a defender table, a midfielder table and a striker table), for example, a defender would have jockeying, clearing, heading, strength.

I'm using the MySqlite3 in python when creating these databases. I can figure out how to write the code once I know what structure my database (ERD) should be in.
[My image shows the relationship between the different members of the team, however, my teacher and I both can't seem to figure out how to structure it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRiUf.png)

[image]

Comment: can you please share your work so far? what is your preliminary ERD?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the picture of where I am at the moment the "defence" tables simply represent the different positions that could be used. sia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only create two entities because they share common attributes. I will merge the manger with player to team member and merge all the positions to position entity. the team_member has a postion_id as a foreign key. [image]

Comment: so depending on position_id each attribute in position entity would be examined? is there a way that I could create it so that each attribute is unique to a certain position?  what is the purpose of position_type? Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: I thought you can combine all the positions, another approach would be creating multiple entities for each position and have those ids for team_members as well but I prefer single position entity